# Go to app button

Tags: facebook

I have created a Facebook app.  The app is running on my hosted server through Facebook.  I have a community sit and a blog site.  How do I get the blue “Go to APP” button for my Facebook pages to drive users to the app?  I cannot find the information in Facebook help files. Sorry if this is a novice question.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a Facebook page for your app. It will have the blue “Go to APP” button that takes the user to your app.

To create a page for your app, click on the “Create Facebook Page” button in Edit App > Advanced > Contact info tab

Answer (score -1):

In that case, as of February 1st, 2012, "App" pages are no longer available (read [Removing App Profile Pages](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/611/)).

Please see this link for completed roadmap changes:
https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/completed-changes/

Comment: I have updated my answer to reflect your clarification.  Sorry for the misunderstanding!

Comment: Thank you, I didn't see that.  I'll try to be more thorough next time.